# What is the correct way to document changes to an object/function in JSDoc?

Tags: jsdoc

Say I have a function that takes one parameter:

```
/**
 * @summary Some function.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 *
 * etc.
 */
function func( a ) {
   // do stuff...
}
```

And then a few versions later support for a second parameter is added. In PHPDoc you can add additional `@since` entries to keep a change log specific to that element:

```
/**
 * @summary Some function.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 * @since 1.2.0 Parameter b was added, because reasons.
 *
 * etc.
 */
function func( a, b ) {
   // do stuff...
}
```

That way it is easy for folks to see when a change like this was introduced. Is there an element "change log" standard in JSDoc?

I've checked the [page for `@since` on usejsdoc.org](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-since.html), but there's no mention of anything like this, or of different tag that should be used for it.

Answer (score 0):

Quite some time since your question, but there is now such a tag of the same name: [`@since`](https://jsdoc.app/tags-since.html)

(And FWIW, you can use [`@version`](https://jsdoc.app/tags-version.html) if you want a version to your particular method.)

Comment: I know about the `@since` tag, but I was wondering if there was any support for essentially using it to create a change log with multiple `@since` entries for a single element.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Since it only mentions "versionDescription" in the signature following the tag, I'd think `@since` does not apply as it only means the "class, method, or other symbol was added in a specific version.", not the parameters.